# Why can't efence detect out-of-bound if size of chunk is not multiple of 4

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault

I've just found that `efence` cannot detect out-of-bound fault, if size of memory chunk is not multiple of 4.

My test code:

```
int main() {
  char *arr;
  int i;
  size_t size_arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 4, 128, 256, 512};
  for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    printf("%s:%d: OOB test size:%lu\n", __func__, __LINE__, size_arr[i]);
    arr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * size_arr[i]);
    arr[size_arr[i]] = 0;
    free(arr);
    printf("%s:%d: next loop\n", __func__, __LINE__);
  }
  ...
}
```

Output:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libefence.so ./test
main:10: OOB test size:1
main:16: next loop
main:10: OOB test size:2
main:16: next loop
main:10: OOB test size:3
main:16: next loop
main:10: OOB test size:5
main:16: next loop
main:10: OOB test size:6
main:16: next loop
main:10: OOB test size:7
main:16: next loop
main:10: OOB test size:9
main:16: next loop
main:10: OOB test size:10
main:16: next loop
main:10: OOB test size:4
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I wonder why `efence` cannot detect those cases.

Comment: Just an assumption therefore no answer... I would expect that `malloc` "rounds up" the allocated size to a multiple of some granularity to reduce fragmentation. Only that enlarged size is then passed to the real allocator code. Therefore efence probable cannot "see" the initial allocation size.

Comment: How are you compiling and linking this?

Answer (score 1):

In this day and age, `efence` should never be used, unless you are using an obscure platform.

You will be very much better off using `-fsanitize=address`, or Valgrind.

> I wonder why efence cannot detect those cases.

On most platforms, data is required to be aligned on a certain boundary, and `malloc` guarantees such alignment. Typical alignment requirements are `4`, `8` or `16`.

With a malloc alignment of `16` and allocation size of `1`, `efence` will not be able to detect any overflow by less than 15 bytes, because it arranges for the end of allocation to be adjacent to page boundary (usually `4096` or more), but must still satisfy the alignment constraints.

Comment: Then, the alignment of my environment will be 4. Is there a simple way to find the alignment requirement?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/efence),

> EF_ALIGNMENT
>
> This is an integer that specifies the alignment for any memory allocations that will be returned by malloc(), calloc(), and realloc(). The value is specified in bytes, thus a value of 4 will cause memory to be aligned to 32-bit boundaries unless your system doesn't have a 8-bit characters. EF_ALIGNMENT is set to sizeof(int) by default, since that is generally the word-size of your CPU.

If you don't set EF_ALIGNMENT, EF_ALIGNMENT is set to sizeof(int), which is 4 in many environments. In this case, `efence` cannot detect described cases.
But if you set EF_ALIGNMENT to 1, `efence` can detect these.